# Inductive load turns on PC mouse RGB

Tags: motor, grounding, rgb, inductive, pc

I have a floor fan connected on the same outlet as my PC.  When the PC is off, if I turn on or turn off the fan the mouse RGB lights up for a split second. The mouse is plugged in to a USB port that doesn't power it when the computer is off. The PSU is turned on. What's the mechanism behind this phenomenon?

[Here is a video of it.](https://youtube.com/shorts/O45mo1YN_bQ?feature=share)

Comment: Oh, it's just "spooky action at a distance" a.k.a. "Quantum Entanglement" -- pay it no mind.

Comment: Unplug the PC from the wall socket and try again.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: the mouse definitely is powered (LEDs need current to light, after all). The PC may have a feature where the port is powered "even if the PC is off" for charging, attachment of devices that could wake the PC up, etc.

Okay, having gotten that out of the way: Computer mice turn off their LEDs to conserve current, especially when not used (moving).  This includes the LED underneath that detect motion.

However, if the LED underneath-to-detect-motion is powered off, how would the mouse ever know you just moved it?

Answer: the LED is on, perhaps very weakly, as long as the mouse has power (from the PC).  It can be very dim at this stage, because it doesn't have to measure "pixels" with any accuracy while asleep -- it just has to notice "Hey, I just moved!" and wake itself up.

So if the LED is on weakly, that implies that the light-sensor (e.g. photodiode) is dealing with a very weak light input at this stage.  The current that a photodiode produces when light is weak can be VERY small.  The mouse circuitry of course can easily work with this very-small current.  But at this stage, it's small.

Then here you go, turning on that big bad unshielded noisy 1970's fan that has big coils and noisy brushes and an arcing switch, and bam! that switch blasts a quick noise pulse throughout your room and beyond, AM and shortwave radios around the house all go "pop"!  And a little bit of that noise pulse lands on the circuitry inside the mouse that was quietly listening for a tiny change in the photodiode current, and boom! the mouse thinks you moved it.  And so it wakes up.

Once it's awake, it listens intently to its photodiode to begin tracking movement, but alas, no movement ensues, and so the mouse goes back to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The lights are on for too long to be powered directly from any kind of inductive kick or flyback energy from the fan.  Also, they are on for the same amount of time each time, suggesting that they are getting some kind of signal that causes the mouse to run the lights for a fixed time period.

> The mouse is plugged in a USB port that doesn't power it when the computer is off.

Maybe.  But is the computer really, completely off, or in a standby or sleep mode.  If the computer is configured to wake up on LAN or USB activity, an RF spike from the fan could trigger the mouse innards to turn on the light.

Comment: The Computer is completely powered off. Can a rf spike affect the computer? The fan is quite further away from the motherboard/psu location let alone the fact that they are in a metal case.

Comment: I'd say it's either a short, transient pulse on the power signal of the Mainboard and PSU (but this should than switch the computer on in my oppionion) or for some reason the PC applies 5Vstby to this Port for a short time... OR the 5V are always on the USB Port and the EMI just starts some kind of initalisatuion routine on the mouse.